# Convert row values into XML tag names and values

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I am using SQL Server 2019 and I have a table like the following:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #Temp
SELECT *
INTO #Temp
FROM (
SELECT 1 Id, 'Name' ParameterName, 'John Smith' ParameterValue UNION
SELECT 1 Id, 'Age' ParameterName, '20' ParameterValue UNION 
SELECT 1 Id, 'Gender' ParameterName, 'Male' ParameterValue UNION
SELECT 2 Id, 'Name' ParameterName, 'Jane Smythe' ParameterValue UNION
SELECT 2 Id, 'Age' ParameterName, '26' ParameterValue UNION 
SELECT 2 Id, 'Org Group' ParameterName, 'Marketing' ParameterValue UNION
SELECT 2 Id, 'Gender' ParameterName, 'Female' ParameterValue) t
ORDER BY 1, 2
```

And I am wanting a query to transform this table into two rows with the Id, and an xml column with the value of the ParameterName as the xml tag and the value of the ParameterValue as the xml value e.g.:

```
<Age>20</Age>
<Gender>Male</Gender>
<Name>John Smith</Name>
```

I have tried the following but its not quite right:

```
SELECT  t.Id
    , (SELECT       t1.ParameterName  
                , t1.ParameterValue
        FROM        #Temp t1
        WHERE       t1.Id = t.Id
        FOR XML AUTO, TYPE)
FROM    #Temp t
GROUP BY t.Id



SELECT  t.Id
    , (SELECT       t1.ParameterName  
                , t1.ParameterValue
        FROM        #Temp t1
        WHERE       t1.Id = t.Id
        FOR XML RAW, ELEMENTS, TYPE)
FROM    #Temp t
GROUP BY t.Id


SELECT  t.Id
    , (SELECT       t1.ParameterName  
                , t1.ParameterValue
        FROM        #Temp t1
        WHERE       t1.Id = t.Id
        FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE)
FROM    #Temp t
GROUP BY t.Id
```

Comment: Do you know all possible `ParameterName` values up front? Otherwise it's very hard to do this accurately in SQL Server

Comment: @lptr That doesn't work well if there are characters that need escaping

Comment: ParameterValue is selected for xml and it is escaped..

Comment: @CharlieFace, no I don't know the list of all possible ParameterNames

Comment: thanks @Iptr. Worked like a charm. If you put your query as an answer I can mark it as the answer.

Comment: @woody…try the query with cast() only [instead of try_cast()]..if there are parameternames which cannot be xml tags..an error will be raised..(try_cast() silences any parameternames which cannot appear as xml elements)

Comment: This is perfect for what I need it for. Thank-you. Happy to mark it as the answer if you can add it in.

Comment: @woody…there are cases that he xml tags might not be correct (eg when the parametername contains “>”)..this could be fixed the same way as the {space} ..replace all characters which cannot appear in a tag with “_”

Comment: @Iptr - yep, no worries. I am using this solely for QA purposes and I wanted it as XML so it would just open a new window in SSMS when I click on the cell in the results window. I have another column in the query that uses STRING_AGG(parameterName) + ': ' + parameterValue) that I can use to check if something is missing but what you sent through is perfect for my needs.

Answer (score 1):

If you know all the possible `ParameterName` values up-front, you can just do conditional aggregation.

```sql
SELECT
  t.Id,
  MAX(CASE WHEN ParameterName = 'Name'      THEN ParameterValue END) Name,
  MAX(CASE WHEN ParameterName = 'Age'       THEN ParameterValue END) Age,
  MAX(CASE WHEN ParameterName = 'Gender'    THEN ParameterValue END) Gender,
  MAX(CASE WHEN ParameterName = 'Org Group' THEN ParameterValue END) Org_Group
FROM #Temp t
GROUP BY
  t.Id
FOR XML PATH('Node'), ROOT('Root')
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=51ecf350d6387b8a78d7561df5c1433c)

---

Without knowing the node names up-front, it becomes much harder, because neither `FOR XML` nor `.query` construction allow dynamic node names.

You need to construct it yourself, and you need to make sure to escape all necessary values.

In the below code, `ParameterValue` is escaped, but `ParameterName` only has spaces removed. You may need to check for other characters also.

```sql
SELECT
  CAST(
    CONCAT(
      '<Node>',
      STRING_AGG(
        CONCAT(
          '<',
          REPLACE(ParameterName, ' ', '_'),
          '>',
          x.txt,
          '</',
          REPLACE(ParameterName, ' ', '_'),
          '>'
        ),
        ''
      ),
      '</Node>'
    ) AS xml
  )
FROM #Temp t
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT ParameterValue [text()]
    FOR XML PATH('')
) x(txt)
GROUP BY
  t.Id
FOR XML PATH(''), ROOT('Root');
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f148eb7555c737ed981de75b8bf9b149)